# Understanding how JAX's tracer vs static work

Tags: python, jax

I'm new to JAX and trying to write a simple code using JAX where at some point I need to use a scipy method. Then I want to take its derivative.

The code doesn't run and gives me error. The following is the code and the error. I read a the documentation of JAX a couple of times but couldn't Figure out what to do to write the code correctly

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import grad, jit, vmap
from jax import random
import numpy as np
import scipy
key = random.PRNGKey(1)

size = 3
x = random.uniform(key, (size, size), dtype=jnp.float32)

def error_func(x):
    dists = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(x, x, metric='euclidean')
    error = jnp.sum(jnp.array(dists))
    return error

error_diff = grad(error_func)

print(error_func(x))
print(error_diff(x))
```

And I get the followig error:

```py
No GPU/TPU found, falling back to CPU. (Set TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0 and rerun for more info.)
3.2158318
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/OneDrive - UW-Madison/opttest/jaxtest6.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(error_diff(x))
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/traceback_util.py", line 166, in reraise_with_filtered_traceback
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/api.py", line 646, in grad_f
    _, g = value_and_grad_f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/traceback_util.py", line 166, in reraise_with_filtered_traceback
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/api.py", line 722, in value_and_grad_f
    ans, vjp_py = _vjp(f_partial, *dyn_args, reduce_axes=reduce_axes)
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/api.py", line 2179, in _vjp
    out_primal, out_vjp = ad.vjp(
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/ad.py", line 139, in vjp
    out_primals, pvals, jaxpr, consts = linearize(traceable, *primals)
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/ad.py", line 128, in linearize
    jaxpr, out_pvals, consts = pe.trace_to_jaxpr_nounits(jvpfun_flat, in_pvals)
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/profiler.py", line 314, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/partial_eval.py", line 777, in trace_to_jaxpr_nounits
    jaxpr, (out_pvals, consts, env) = fun.call_wrapped(pvals)
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/linear_util.py", line 188, in call_wrapped
    ans = self.f(*args, **dict(self.params, **kwargs))
  File "/mnt/d/OneDrive - UW-Madison/opttest/jaxtest6.py", line 15, in error_func
    dists = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(x, x, metric='euclidean')
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 2909, in cdist
    XA = np.asarray(XA)
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 598, in __array__
    raise TracerArrayConversionError(self)
jax._src.traceback_util.UnfilteredStackTrace: jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError: The numpy.ndarray conversion method __array__() was called on the JAX Tracer object Traced<ConcreteArray([[0.7551559  0.3129729  0.12388372]
 [0.548188   0.8851279  0.30576992]
 [0.82008433 0.95633745 0.3566252 ]], dtype=float32)>with<JVPTrace(level=2/0)> with
  primal = Array([[0.7551559 , 0.3129729 , 0.12388372],
       [0.548188  , 0.8851279 , 0.30576992],
       [0.82008433, 0.95633745, 0.3566252 ]], dtype=float32)
  tangent = Traced<ShapedArray(float32[3,3])>with<JaxprTrace(level=1/0)> with
    pval = (ShapedArray(float32[3,3]), None)
    recipe = LambdaBinding()
See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError

The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified.

--------------------

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/OneDrive - UW-Madison/opttest/jaxtest6.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(error_diff(x))
  File "/mnt/d/OneDrive - UW-Madison/opttest/jaxtest6.py", line 15, in error_func
    dists = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(x, x, metric='euclidean')
  File "/home/sattarian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 2909, in cdist
    XA = np.asarray(XA)
jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError: The numpy.ndarray conversion method __array__() was called on the JAX Tracer object Traced<ConcreteArray([[0.7551559  0.3129729  0.12388372]
 [0.548188   0.8851279  0.30576992]
 [0.82008433 0.95633745 0.3566252 ]], dtype=float32)>with<JVPTrace(level=2/0)> with
  primal = Array([[0.7551559 , 0.3129729 , 0.12388372],
       [0.548188  , 0.8851279 , 0.30576992],
       [0.82008433, 0.95633745, 0.3566252 ]], dtype=float32)
  tangent = Traced<ShapedArray(float32[3,3])>with<JaxprTrace(level=1/0)> with
    pval = (ShapedArray(float32[3,3]), None)
    recipe = LambdaBinding()
See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAX transformations only work on JAX functions, not numpy or scipy functions (this is discussed briefly at the [link](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError) shown in the error message above) If you want to use `grad` and other JAX transformations, you need to write your logic using JAX operations, not operations from `numpy`, `scipy`, or other non-JAX-compatible libraries.

JAX does not currently include any wrappers of `scipy.spatial.distance` (though there are some in progress, see [#16147](https://github.com/google/jax/pull/16147)), so the best option would be to write the code yourself. Fortunately, `cdist` is pretty straightforward:

```py
def cdist(x, y, metric='euclidean'):
  assert x.ndim == y.ndim == 2
  if metric != 'euclidean':
    raise NotImplementedError(f"{metric=}")
  return jnp.sqrt(jnp.sum((x[:, None, :] - y[None, :, :]) ** 2, axis=-1))

def error_func(x):
    dists = cdist(x, x, metric='euclidean')
    error = jnp.sum(dists)
    return error

error_diff = grad(error_func)

print(error_func(x))
# 3.2158318

print(error_diff(x))
# [[nan nan nan]
#  [nan nan nan]
#  [nan nan nan]]
```

You'll notice that the gradient is everywhere `nan`. This is the expected result due to the fact that `grad(jnp.sqrt)(0.0)` diverges (returns infinity), and `0.0 * inf` by definition is `nan`.